# Site title not appearing in google search results (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

My site title not appearing in google search results.
How can i fix this?

Google search: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv8Oc.png

Site title: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfJqo.png

Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQqLM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When did you make this change? It takes time for Google to change a page title (a few days).
You may take a look at [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/title-link).

You can also add your website to Google Search Console and [Ask Google to recrawl your URLs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/ask-google-to-recrawl).